# Act As Messagable group conversation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to initiate a group message with the `acts_as_messagable` gem without needing to "join" them in after the first message is sent? It looks like the Mailboxer gem has this functionality but I'd rather not use it as it seems a bit overkill for my needs

From the [docs](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable)

```
@message =  @alice.send_message(@bob, :topic => "Helou bob!", :body => "What's up?")
@reply_message = @sukhi.reply_to(@message, "Hi there!", "I would like to join to this conversation!")
@sec_reply_message = @bob.reply_to(@message, "Hi!", "Fine!")
@third_reply_message = @alice.reply_to(@reply_message, "hi!", "no problem")
```

I'd much rather not need to "join" someone to the conversation but rather include everyone on the very first message. Anyone know a good work around?